# Stihl FS 55 Trigger Problem

Tags: tools

I have a Stihl FS 55 weed eater.  The trigger is no longer loose and easy to use. There is also a long black plastic piece on the top near the on/off switch that snapped off.  The trimmer still works, but I'd like to fix it.  I looked on Youtube and did some Googling but didn't find what I need.

Are there any guides or videos anyone knows of that could help me get the right parts and do the repair?

[image: top]
[image: trigger2]

[image: trigger]

Comment: Triggers are simple handles that pull a wire/steel rod.  If stiff then probably have dirt built up inside.  Undo the housing carefully, clean and use light oil on the trigger and wire.